# How can I make gradient of some pieces of circle?

Tags: qt

I want to make an gradient piece of a circle,in QT.I have drawPie() functions for generate the pieces.How can I do that?

```
 void Sculpture::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, 
 QWidget *widget)
  {
  QRectF rec = boundingRect();
  QBrush Brush(Qt::red);
  QBrush BrushRadar(Qt::green);


  painter->setBrush(BrushRadar);
  int startAngle = 0 * 16;
  int spanAngle = 60 * 16;

  painter->drawPie(rec,startAngle,spanAngle);

  QGradient grad1(drawPie());//HOW CAN I IMPLEMENT
  grad1.setColorAt(0.2, Qt::green);//HOW CAN I IMPLEMENT

  }
```

Comment: Create your gradient first. Let's call it `grad`. You can then set that gradient as your painter's brush: `painter->setBrush( QBrush( grad1 ) );`

Comment: Appreciate it!Thanks

Comment: Elif Kantar, if you have succeeded in your endeavor, you could answer the question yourself, and mark it as accepted... :)